# GNU screen shift-tab issue

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

GNU screen seems to catch the Shift-Tab key combination which is mighty unfortunate as i'm using this combination in vim. Has anyone noticed such behaviour? How can i change it?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your `~/.screenrc` and `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: What happens when you press `Ctrl+V Shift+Tab` in insert mode 1: outside and 2: inside `screen`?

Comment: @Gilles: i get ^[[Z] in both cases, to be more specific, it's the minibufexpl vim plugin that doesn't seem to react to the Shift-tab within screen the way it does when i'm not running screen (the key combination moves the cursor to the previous buffer label)

Comment: @Dennis: i removed both of them (and my .vim folder, except .vim/plugin/minibufexpl.vim) to isolate the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set t_kB=^[[Z
```

To insert the `^[` (escape character) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd> (don't type literal carat-leftbracket).

It's already set in the terminfo file for xterm, but not in the ones for screen.

Alternatively, you can simply set `TERM=xterm` in the shell.

You can try these at a shell prompt to see the difference:

```
infocmp -I xterm | grep cbt
infocmp -I screen | grep cbt
```

The terminfo capabilities `cbt` and `kcbt` correspond to the termcap capabilities `bt` and `kB` respectively.

Comment: I have also found this vim wiki link useful (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/GNU_Screen_integration) for fixing the home/end/del keys